# Hazelcast creates 3 nodes/members when configured as Hibernate L2 cache

Tags: hibernate, grails, hazelcast

Hazelcast creates 3 nodes/members when configured as Hibernate L2 cache.

Why? How do I control this?

I am using Hazelcast 3.2.6 with default configuration and Grails 2.2.3.

Comment: Do you create multiple Hibernate instances?

Comment: @noctarius That is the reason behind it - we have three db's configured in hibernate!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an instanceName for all Hazelcast instances used in the Hibernate configurations. Then all will reuse the same HazelcastInstance (referred to by the name).

To set the instance name please use the following property in the Hibernate config all set to the same value:

```
hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name
```

Set as:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name">common_name</property>
```

Comment: Even with this property set, it still creates three nodes for the three databases configured in Hibernate. If one node is populated with an entity, the same reflects in all 3 nodes and the 3 nodes of another instance of the same application. I am using default Hazelcast configuration. If the entity is going to show up in all 3 nodes, then why does it create 3 nodes?

Comment: If it still does please create a small unittest that shows the problem and open a github issue, this is a bug then.

Comment: I have filed this as a bug here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4374